# What is the temperature at which one-half of the oscillators in a Debye solid are expected to be in the ground state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phonons

This is a slightly reworded question picked up from Pathria and Beale's textbook on Statistical Mechanics. I'm unable to even get started on the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: First, you can find the probability for the quantum oscillator to be in the ground state if the temperature is $\theta$.

Comment: So integrate over all possible frequencies?

Comment: Summation of probability over all oscillators gives the mean value of the number of oscillators in the ground state.

Comment: Could you please illustrate the solution better? I get what you're saying, but I'm not sure how I would accomplish the steps.

Comment: It looks like a homework task. In this case, you should show your attempt to solve the problem.